# Importing file from a different directory in another file

Tags: python

I am new to python and have been trying to import a function that lies in a different file.

My file tree is like below

```
MainDir 
  ->folder1
     ->file1.py
 ->CommonFunctions.py
```

CommonFunctions.py lies in the main directory and I want to use the functions of CommonFunctions.py in file1.py

My CommonFunction.py has below code

```
class CommonFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
            logging.info('CALLED')
```

I want to use the setUp function from file1.py

I have tried imports but thats not working, any help really appreciated.
FYI, am using Python 2.7

Comment: If you're new to python use python 3

Comment: Important question: is `file1` meant to be a module (to be imported and used elsewhere) or a script (to be run and have effects)?

Comment: or just put all code in one folder and make proper python folder

Comment: @Draconis I want CommonFunctions.py file to be imported and used in file1.py

Comment: @Coder Yes, but is `file1` meant to be a module or a script? In Python it makes a big difference: things that work in modules don't necessarily work in scripts.

Comment: Its meant to be script

Answer (score 0):

Use two dots to specify one directory up (one dot would mean current directory instead of python path):

```
from ..CommonFunctions import random_func
```

From [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/):

> One leading dot means the current package where the module making the import exists. Two dots means up one package level. Three dots is up two levels, etc. So if you execute from . import mod from a module in the pkg package then you will end up importing pkg.mod. If you execute from ..subpkg2 import mod from within pkg.subpkg1 you will import pkg.subpkg2.mod.

Remember that you can always append to system path like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/file')

import file
```

Comment: @Alec, I was trying using your given secnd method of importing sys, however in my case I dont need to insert but actually go up one level, can I do that?

Comment: `sys.path.append(path_to_parent)`. Just use the first method though, it's easier